# Restore directory from VSS on Windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, vss

Is it possible to restore specific directory from shadow copy snapshot of logical disk in Windows 2003?

I have logical disk (also configured as network share) on Windows 2003 server. I have set up automatic Shadow Copy creation points (twice a day). I can see these points in properties of the logical disk.

Now I want to recovery specific directory from the past - I can see the correct date, but system (properties dialog of the logical disk) allows me only to restore whole disk to past state.

I tried to look in properties of specific directory - to restore it there, but there is no such tab in these properties, I tried to connect from Win 7 desktop to that network share, but in properties on Win7 desktop, "it could not find any previous versions" of that file/directory/network share.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install support for Windows XP network clients for Windows 2003 VSS, can be downloaded here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/thankyou.aspx?familyId=e382358f-33c3-4de7-acd8-a33ac92d295e&displayLang=cs

After installation, it can be restored from network share on the client using properties on directory.

I could not make it work from Windows 7 ultimate.